# ngToast newestOnTop doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toast

I am trying to get the toasts messages created by ngToast to appear on top of each other. On the documentation http://tamerayd.in/ngToast/# I found a parameter called "newestOnTop". I used it this way in my app.coffee:

```
ngToastProvider.configure {
    newestOnTop: true
}
```

However my new toasts still appear behind the previous one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newestOnTop` wasn't added until fairly recently on [this commit](https://github.com/tameraydin/ngToast/commit/391026f4ee1699c545e8a91a8895e71ad7180909) (in march 2016). Open the ngtoast source in your project packages and search for newestOnTop to see if it's actually there.